# Unable to install IPA from Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios7, ios8, xcode6, ipa, ios8.1

Updated a iPad app to ios8, it's working fine when run from Xcode 6.1. when try to install ipa in iPad it shows installing, but installation not completed in iPad. The same project ipa from Xcode 4.5.1 can install on iPad.

I tried ipa from Xcode 6.1 for another project is working fine on iPad. Any one can help me please. I didn't get any solution.

Message in console is:

19/11/14 3:29:05.578 pm Xcode[251]: plugin com.getdropbox.dropbox.garcon interrupted

19/11/14 3:30:18.065 pm iTunes[250]: Entered:_AMMuxedVersion2DeviceConnected, mux-device:3

19/11/14 3:30:18.073 pm iTunes[250]: tid:18833 - unable to query device capabilities

19/11/14 3:30:57.651 pm iTunes[250]: AMDeviceSecureTransferPath (thread 0x10de38000): disableDelta: FALSE

19/11/14 3:30:57.651 pm iTunes[250]: AMDeviceSecureTransferPath (thread 0x10de38000): Trying SZConduit for transfer

19/11/14 3:30:57.804 pm iTunes[250]: nuke_path (thread 0x10de38000): AFCRemovePath of 'PublicStaging/Project1.ipa' returned 8

Comment: Any error messages from console logs, etc?

Comment: No i didn't get any error  messages.

Comment: Did you look for them (i.e. use `Console.app`)?

Comment: console message added in question

Answer (score 0):

The ipa file needs to contain either:

- Enterprise Provisioning Profile
- Developer Provisioning Profile with your iPad's UDID

If it doesn't contain the above, you won't be able to install it in your iPad.

Comment: Ipad UDID included in the Profile, and the same project ipa from Xcode 4.5.1 can install on iPad.